# How to solve "BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Fee::round()" error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[image: The teams i want retrieve are marked with red pen][image]In my fees table there is two column named team and round. Now i want to check that which team has play more than two rounds. Then I want to retrieve all the teams name.

```
$teams =Fee::has('round','>',2)->get();
        foreach ($teams as $key => $team) {
            $list[]=$team->team;
        }
        dd($list);
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: it showing me error, please see the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method is for checking if a relationship exists. In this case it is looking for a relationship called `round`, however, since you don't have one it will thrown an error.

If you want to add a constraint for a column then just use `where()`:

```
$teams = Fee::where('round', '>', 2)->get();

$list = []; 

foreach ($teams as $key => $team) {
    $list[] = $team->team;
}

dd($list);
```

Comment: it shows me undefined variable "list". Could you tell me why?

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Because you have not defined a variable called `$list`. You'll just need to add `$list = [];` before your `foreach` loop. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: it solves the error but it doesnot showing any results. Do I add the image of my dd($list) and my table fees?????

Comment: @TanvirAhmed To be honest, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. There are a few of reasons why you might not have any items in your list array. Are there definitely results being returned i.e. what does `dd($teams->count())` give you?

Comment: @TanvirAhmed: so this is reason you are getting no result

Comment: could you help me to getting appropriate result. I will add the image of my table with team marked with red pen which I want retrieve

Comment: @TanvirAhmed The image you've added shows that `round` is not a number so `round > 2` is never going to work. How many different rounds are there and what are they?

Comment: there are 3 rounds: first, ko and final.

Comment: @TanvirAhmed and are you just  wanting to get the ones that are `final`??

Comment: something like select all records grouped by match name then get only those who have atleast 3 rounds

Comment: oh shit that's a easy one but my thinking takes me to the in complex way, by the way thanks for the idea. thank you @Ross WIlson